# Connection to node could not be established

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have tried to send a message with apache kafka on a spring project, I have respect all the signes included in spring documentation .. when I try to produce a message with postman it won't be sended
and show me  in the terminal the below message:

```
2022-08-05 12:46:51.869  WARN 3012 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-08-05 12:46:51.869  WARN 3012 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, Kafka is not running at `localhost:9092`. Perhaps you configured it with a different port?

The broker needs to be up and healthy for your Kafka Producer to send data to it.

It is recommended you test your Kafka connection with included `kafka-console-producer` and consumer tools rather than POSTMan.